# PHP - Declare type for property

Tags: php, .net

I have an API I built in .Net. I'm calling the API using PHP objects using cURL. Right now I'm just building a library of objects but I need to make sure I convert each object correctly. How do I define a type for a variable in PHP? I thought you could cast it but gives error:

PHP:

```
    <?php
   class OAuth
   {
       var $Administrator;
       var $Password;
   }
?>
```

.Net

```
public class OAuth
{
    public string Administrator { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

When I call it I will serialize my PHP object to Json. So I want to make sure if will work. I'm a newb to PHP so I'm sorry if this seems like a really newb question.

EDIT::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Here is the issue I'm running into and the reason I asked this question.

```
function Test_WBG_Conntection()
    {
        //WBG Object
        $OAuth = new OAuth;
        $OAuth->Administrator = 'username';
        $OAuth->Password = 'password';
        //API URL "http://www.whiteboxgaming.xyz:34188/";
        $url = $endpoint.'api/WhiteBoXGaming/Post_TestAPI';


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($OAuth));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if($response === FALSE)
        {
            echo "cURL Error" . curl_error($ch);
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }
```

Error:
cURL ErrorFailed to connect to www.whiteboxgaming.xyz port 34188: Connection refused

My API as mentioned before is built using ASP .Net but my website is PHP. Just trying to make a call to the API in PHP. I assume it should not be a issue because its just converting to JSON and sending receiving etc.  Is something wrong in my cURL or is it in my Object its self?

UPDATE::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

I'm a little confused. I converted my .Net (c#) version to Json using a converter and compared to converting the PHP to Json:

```
.Net
{
  "administrator": null,
  "password": null
}

PHP

{
    "Administrator": null,
    "Password": null
}
```

I assume case matters. Maybe I just need to make my PHP class lower case?

Comment: _gives error_ you say?

Comment: There are no typed properties in php, not [until php 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php) but there are [type-hints](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) in other versions.

Comment: PHP is a loosely typed language, you can't define the type of a property (not until 7.4 version). However, that's not an impediment for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Where's that error message you are talking about?

Comment: Not sure what version I have, I'm using Blue Host for a Word Press website. I don't think its 7. When I tried to declare variable type it gave me syntax error.